# clicking label doesn't click checkbox in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox, onclick, label

I have created a form where a user can pick options prior to submitting the form. I am hiding the checkboxes with `display: none` and am styling the `<label>` so that when the user clicks the label it triggers the checkbox.

I've got this to work in vanilla HTML and CSS, however when I try this in React, clicking the label doesn't do anything.  **ONLY**  if I unhide the checkbox am I able to click on the checkbox and am able to see the label styling. I want to hide the checkbox though.

Does anyone know how to hide the checkbox and still able to click the label in ReactJS?

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/fleech/pen/dXymrz?editors=1100) of what I am trying to build in ReactJS.

Answer (score 31):

Use `htmlFor` instead of `for` in react (see react [supported attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes)):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check3"/> Fish
<label htmlFor="check3"><span class="fa fa-check"/></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was already stated - use `htmlFor` and then try adding `onClick` event on `label` instead of on an `input`. This will add/remove `checked` attribute on the input itself. I assume that you already use `defaultChecked` attribute on your input.