# onChange not getting called React

Tags: reactjs, onchange

I'm trying to debug a react checkbox and the onChange event doesn't ever get called. I have added a console.log to test and this doesn't ever run. Here is the code for the checkbox. What is the issue?

```
return (
    <div className="RampPane">
      <div className="RampPane--content">
        <p className="RampText">{transaction.merchant} </p>
        <b>{moneyFormatter.format(transaction.amount)}</b>
        <p className="RampText--hushed RampText--s">
          {transaction.employee.firstName} {transaction.employee.lastName} - {transaction.date}
        </p>
      </div>
      <InputCheckbox
        id={transaction.id}
        checked={approved}
        disabled={loading}
        onChange={async (newValue) => {
          console.log("click")
          await consumerSetTransactionApproval({
            transactionId: transaction.id,
            newValue,
          })

          setApproved(newValue)
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

Here is the InputCheckBox Component

```
return (
    <div className="RampInputCheckbox--container" data-testid={inputId}>
      <label
        className={classNames("RampInputCheckbox--label", {
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-checked": checked,
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-disabled": disabled,
        })}
      />
      <input
        id={inputId}
        type="checkbox"
        className="RampInputCheckbox--input"
        checked={checked}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={() => onChange(!checked)}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the InputCheckbox component...

Comment: Make sure to share the proper codebase when you post a question. You have made a custom component so it's very hard to understand what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for InputCheckBox Component

```
return (
    <div className="RampInputCheckbox--container" data-testid={inputId}>
      <label
        className={classNames("RampInputCheckbox--label", {
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-checked": checked,
          "RampInputCheckbox--label-disabled": disabled,
        })}
        htmlFor={inputId}
      />
      <input
        id={inputId}
        type="checkbox"
        className="RampInputCheckbox--input"
        checked={checked}
        disabled={disabled}
        onChange={() => onChange(!checked)}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

This works!

Comment: I'm just wondering how did you know to use this attribute htmlFor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38839080/8802812 
Here buddy! Do upvote!

Answer (score 0):

If the InputCheckBox is a custom built react component that renders an html input element try checking that the onChange handler is passed to the root component correctly
IF Not try including the component here to get a better insight

Comment: I have just included it

Comment: Try to encapsulate the handler function and pass it without running it onChange={handlerFunction}

Comment: When I do that the event is still not registering

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).